# How do I solve this error with gradle in ReactNative on Linux?

Tags: android, linux, reactjs, react-native

Note: I actually just solved this and I am posting my solution here since it was a vague error message that took some time to solve. Hopefully, I can help out one other person!

`> react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html`

Looking around online, I saw similar error messages, but which were more verbose and solved in other ways. My solution is luckily simple, and it's in the answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make `./android/gradlew` an executable. (`chmod +x android/gradlew`)

You can test that it's working with `cd android && ./gradlew`

This was eventualy solved by just trying `./gradlew` and getting the more telling error message that it needs to be executable.

Good luck with the rest of your project, if you stumbled into this error!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an actual device or a emulator connected? In case you don't refer the setup of GenyMotion (https://www.genymotion.com/download/) and once done create an emulator. This should solve your issue. Let me know if you still face the problem